# Convert PDF file to a single HTML file

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdf-to-html, document-conversion

I am trying to convert a PDF document to a single HTML file in java. Most of the converters online converts one PDF file to multiple HTML files. I want to convert the whole PDF to a single HTML file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to extract just the text, or also formatting?

Answer (score 3):

> Any suggestions?

You might always write some code using the [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) API to write a single document that incorporates the `body` of each of the multiple HTML files.  Combining styles & style-sheets (CSS) might be a bit more tricky (especially if the original HTML uses 'id' elements).

---

Though I find it hard to believe there is *not* a converter out there in which 'single document' is an option.  I recommend searching further.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to parse your PDF document with [itext](http://itextpdf.com/) and then generate your html file. 
I must admit I haven't checked if it is doable though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.jpedal.org/html_index.php which has an optiont to write to single file.