# How to display PDFs in a SWT-Application?

Tags: java, pdf, swt, eclipse-rcp

What is the best way to display PDFs in a swt application? I would prefer an open source solution.

Comment: could you also open a pdf reader?

Comment: You can find some in this question: [Java PDF Viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437910/java-pdf-viewer)

Comment: No an external PDF-Reader is not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061288/convert-pdf-file-to-a-single-html-file if there is nothing else left, you could try to convert it to HTML and use the Browser widget

Answer (score 5):

If you can assume that a system-pdf viewer is installed, you can use the `Browser` widget by setting the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>

</head>
<body onResize="fit();">
<embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="http://www.adobe.com/security/pdfs/riskcompliance_faq.pdf"
    id="pdfDocument">
</embed>    
<script type="text/javascript">
fit();
function fit() {
 var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
//Non-IE
myWidth = window.innerWidth;
myHeight = window.innerHeight;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 4 compatible
myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}
document.getElementById('pdfDocument').width = myWidth;
document.getElementById('pdfDocument').height = myHeight;
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The src of the embed tag must point to the desired pdf, for local files: `file://myPath/../test.pdf`